Processing dataset for Llama 3.1 Instruct using PyTorch
Hey I am finetuning Llama 3.1 Instruct using PyTorch. I was wondering how to correctly process the dataset. Can you tell me if I am using the prompt template correctly and can I pass the whole prompt in my realprompt column as input to the model or would I need to separate it into input and target (answer) for the model so it can be processed correctly? Am I using the right padding token?
This is my code:
import os
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, random_split
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast
from datasets import load_dataset

# Load the dataset
dataset = load_dataset("Shekswess/medical_llama3_instruct_dataset")

# Create prompt structure
def create_realprompt(entry):
    return (
        f"<|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>{entry['instruction']}<|eot_id|>"
        f"<|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>{entry['input']}<|eot_id|>"
        f"<|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>{entry['output']}<|eot_id|>"
    )

# Apply the function to create the column realprompt
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: {"realprompt": create_realprompt(x)})

# Look at the first row to check the new colum
print("Sample row from dataset:", dataset['train'][1])

# Custom Dataset class
class MedicalDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, tokenizer, max_length=512):
        self.data = data
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

        if self.tokenizer.pad_token is None:
            self.tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '<|finetune_right_pad_id|>'})

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Use realprompt from the dataset
        prompt = self.data[idx]['realprompt']

        # Print the raw prompt before tokenization
        #print(f"\nRaw prompt: {prompt}")

        # Tokenize the prompt using the tokenizer
        tokenized_prompt = self.tokenizer.encode(prompt, truncation=True, padding='max_length', max_length=self.max_length)

        # Print the tokenized prompt
        #print(f"Tokenized prompt (IDs): {tokenized_prompt}")

        # Convert to tensor
        return torch.tensor(tokenized_prompt)

# Load the tokenizer using the predownloaded files
tokenizer_path = "checkpoints/meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct/meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct"
tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(tokenizer_file=os.path.join(tokenizer_path, "tokenizer.json"))

# Create PyTorch Dataset 
processed_data = [{"realprompt": entry['realprompt']} for entry in dataset['train']]
medical_dataset = MedicalDataset(processed_data, tokenizer)

# Split into training and validation sets
train_size = int(0.8 * len(medical_dataset))
val_size = len(medical_dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(medical_dataset, [train_size, val_size])

# Create DataLoaders
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=False)

This is the example output of the first row of realprompt:
Sample row from dataset: {'output': 'Clear cell tumors are part of the surface epithelial-stromal tumor group of Ovarian cancers, accounting for 6% of these neoplastic cases. Clear cell tumors are also associated with the pancreas and salivary glands.\r\nBenign and borderline variants of this neoplasm are rare, and most cases are malignant.\r\nTypically, they are cystic neoplasms with polypoid masses that protrude into the cyst.\r\nOn microscopic pathological examination, they are composed of cells with clear cytoplasm (that contains glycogen) and hob nail cells (from which the glycogen has been secreted).\r\nThe pattern may be glandular, papillary or solid.', 'input': 'What does "Clear: cell" mean?', 'instruction': 'Answer the question truthfully, you are a medical professional.', 'prompt': '<|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|> Answer the question truthfully, you are a medical professional.<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|> This is the question: What does "Clear: cell" mean?<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|> Clear cell tumors are part of the surface epithelial-stromal tumor group of Ovarian cancers, accounting for 6% of these neoplastic cases. Clear cell tumors are also associated with the pancreas and salivary glands.\r\nBenign and borderline variants of this neoplasm are rare, and most cases are malignant.\r\nTypically, they are cystic neoplasms with polypoid masses that protrude into the cyst.\r\nOn microscopic pathological examination, they are composed of cells with clear cytoplasm (that contains glycogen) and hob nail cells (from which the glycogen has been secreted).\r\nThe pattern may be glandular, papillary or solid.<|eot_id|>', 'realprompt': '<|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>Answer the question truthfully, you are a medical professional.<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>What does "Clear: cell" mean?<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>Clear cell tumors are part of the surface epithelial-stromal tumor group of Ovarian cancers, accounting for 6% of these neoplastic cases. Clear cell tumors are also associated with the pancreas and salivary glands.\r\nBenign and borderline variants of this neoplasm are rare, and most cases are malignant.\r\nTypically, they are cystic neoplasms with polypoid masses that protrude into the cyst.\r\nOn microscopic pathological examination, they are composed of cells with clear cytoplasm (that contains glycogen) and hob nail cells (from which the glycogen has been secreted).\r\nThe pattern may be glandular, papillary or solid.<|eot_id|>'}

I tried to use the realprompt row to train my model and i got a reasonable loss but I am unsure if I need to specify the target and input sequences more specifically or if the model just learns that my whole prompt is just the input sequence and therefore does not learn correctly. So I expected the loss to be bad but it kept improving through training so I am wondering if my setup is correct and working?
